DELETE request with body from TRESTRequest
I know, that TRESTRequest is not designed to send body in DELETE requests. But these days many servers accept such requests.
Is there a way to somehow get around this component flaw?
For example, this can be done with TIdHTTP.
P.S. Indeed, TRESTRequest supports DELETE request with a body in Embarcadero Delphi version 10.3 and later. (version 10.2 and earlier - does not support)


I know, that TRESTRequest is not designed to send body in DELETE requests.

Actually, it is designed that way, at least in Delphi 10.3 and later (I don't have Delphi 10.2 to check with).

Is there a way to somehow get around this component flaw?

Add an item to the TRESTRequest.Params property and set its Kind property to pkREQUESTBODY.  You can store your body data in the item's Stream or Value property.
Alternatively, you can use TRESTRequest.AddBody(), which will add a pkREQUESTBODY item to TRESTRequest.Params for you.

Yes, we can add a body via TRESTRequest.AddBody() or Params.AddItem Kind := pkREQUESTBODY But if we call the RESTRequest.Execute procedure with RESTRequest.Method := rmDELETE, then in any case the request will be sent without a body. Does it work differently in version 10.3?

I haven't tried it myself, but just looking at the source code for TRESTRequest.Execute() in 10.3 and 12.0, if a body is present then a TStream is prepared for it and passed to TRESTClient.HttpClient.Delete() (TRESTHTTP), which passes it to THTTPClient.Execute(). Offhand, I don't see anything in there that would prevent a body from being sent for a DELETE request, unless it is happening inside of whatever OS API that THTTPClient uses internally (like WinHTTP on Windows, etc).

Take a closer look. TRESTHTTP has two versions of Execute. For GET and DELETE - use TRESTHTTP.Execute(const AMethod: string; AURL: string; AResponseContent: TStream). For PUT and POST - TRESTHTTP.Execute(const AMethod: string; AURL: string; ASource, AResponseContent: TStream), where ASource is the body of the request. Thereby, DELETE request doesn't send the body. AResponseContent - data of response.

In 10.3 and later. TRESTHTTP.Delete() has an overload which accepts an ASource stream, and that overload is called by TCustomRESTRequest.Execute() for a DELETE request: case Method of ... TRESTRequestMethod.rmDELETE: FClient.HTTPClient.Delete(LURL, LBodyStream, LResponseStream); ... end; So, it sounds like this feature is lacking in 10.2, and TRESTHTTP.Execute() is private so you can't call it yourself directly.  So I think you are SOL without upgrading.

It turns out, that my version - 10.2 was the last one, that did not support sending body with delete requests? I am so "lucky" guy! Thank you for the advice. What does SOL mean?

@HeathRow SOL = "Sh** Out of Luck"
